# What is the effect of the reflection coefficient?

Tags: transmission-line, electromagnetic, transmission

I know that the reflection coefficient is the ratio of the backwards wave with the forward wave in terms of the characteristic and load impedances. But what does this mean? Does this represent a loss in energy in the line? Is the backwards wave creating a loss in the forward wave? How does this ratio affect the line?

Comment: Reflections cause some portion of the energy inserted into one end of a transmission line to not reach the other end (because it is reflected) and hence it results in less energy being delivered to the load. It does not directly result in a loss of energy /dissipation of energy to heat, for that you need the energy of the wave to be dissipated either in the load, the source or in losses in the cable.

Comment: so that reflected portion stays in the line? kind of like a wave being pulled back and forth where the water in the middle kinda keeps swaying back and forth but staying there in the "line", Would this be a right way of thinking about it?

Comment: "so that reflected portion stays in the line? kind of like a wave being pulled back and forth where the water in the middle kinda keeps swaying back and forth but staying there in the "line", Would this be a right way of thinking about it?" Only if the reflected wave is reflected again in the source end, then yeah thats a good way to think of it, however most often the source will be fairly well matched to the transmission line and so when the wave reaches back to the beginning of the TL it will dissipate its energy in the source, which delivered it in the first place..

Comment: ...Which by the way can cause big problems for the source, this is why often RF transmitters need protection agains reflected waves, one such protection is called a circulator.

Comment: So if I were to take a battery and use a converter to turn it into an AC source for a "transmission line" would the battery see that reflection as not really wasted since it's energy going back into the source?

Comment: Yes and no, It depends on the type of "converter", or rather amplifier, you use. A FET based full h-bridge is an example of when the energy will go back into the battery, but in the case of for example a bjt based common-emitter amplifier the energy will not go back into the battery but will be dissipated as heat in the output impedance of the amplifier.

Comment: That's hella interesting, thanks for the explanation @Vinzent

Answer (score 1):

A reflection coefficient is defined at the junction between two media, usually transmission lines, of different impedance.

At the junction, the power travelling along the first line is split into some power travelling forward into the second line, and some power reflected back along the first.

As such, there is no power dissipation at the line junction. However, the fraction of incident power that gets reflected is no longer available to the second line. It depends on what is driving the first line whether that power eventually gets dissipated or not. A generator with any sort of resistive output impedance will dissipate that power.

Answer (score 0):

A radio receiver with 3dB reflection coefficient will exhibit (at least) a 3dB worse SNR signal-noise-ratio; often such large S11 will not be usable, because of competitive reasons (consider a cellsite with frequent dropped-service behaviors, such that subscribers switch to another service provider).

In extremely wide-band systems, often connected to large parabolic dishes that vacuum up all the energy across all bands, the reflection coefficient is tolerated (and even removed with computer calibration during direction-finding monopulse behaviors)

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to your question, you said:

> like a wave being pulled back and forth where the water in the middle kinda keeps swaying back and forth but staying there

This is a very good way to visualize what is happening, and is called a [standing wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave). It occurs, because two waves - one coming from the source and one reflected - interfere. The envelope of such a wave has voltage maxima and minima  in regular intervals.
As you correctly stated, the reflection coefficient describes the amplitude ratio of these waves. Another way of expressing the same effect is the "voltage standing wave ratio" ([VSWR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio)), which relates the maximum and minimum envelope voltage on the line. VSWR and refelction coefficient can be directly converted into each other.

Note that the reflection coefficient can be a complex number, in which case its argument (angle against real axis) describes that a phase shift occures in the moment of reflection. This happens for example if the line is terminated with a reactive load.

In practice, reflection is undesireable in RF circuits in most cases. Most importantly, it means that not all available power is transmitted to a the load: Consider an antenna catching a few picowatts (or less), and the reciever amplifier reflects that power right back - wasting our precious signal! The power is not dissipated per se, but it is no longer usable for our application.
Other typical implications include:

- reduced signal-to-noise ratio (SNR)
- worse antenna performance
- instability or even oscillation in amplifiers

To avoid these problems, [impedance matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) networks are used. They are LC or transmission line networks that can present the correct impedance to a line as to minimize reflection over a certain range of frequencies.